# How to extract and save using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and just downloaded QGIS 2.4 Chugiak.

I am practicing QGIS by using training manual, as mentioned in above subject.

I have questions in regard with the sentences in page 7:

> You should then extract and save the following fields from the lines
>   and points layers to their corresponding directories:
>
> - lines: “highway != ‘NULL”’ to roads, and “waterway != ‘NULL”’ to rivers
> - points: “place != ‘NULL”’ to places

How do I extract and save?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your questions are just very basic GIS management operations. If you don't know how to do a select by attribute or export data, you should first read the general QGIS operation manual that explains it.

Nevertheless, in order to extract and save, do the following:

1. Have your polyline and point layers loaded in your project table of contents
2. Make sure the `Attributes` toolbar is active
3. Select the relevant active layer in the table of contents (lines, or points, per the desired query)
4. Click on the `Select features using an expression` tool
5. Enter the query syntax you posted above in the `Expression` window, press `Select`, then `Close`
6. You should have the relevant lines/point highlighted on your map
7. Right-click the layer in the table of contents and choose `Save as`, then proceed to save the layer to the desired directory, while making sure that the `Save only selected features` box is checked.
8. press `Deselect features` in the Attributes toolbar and repeat stages 3-7.

Good luck.